# Restarting a timer in the onResume() method?

Tags: java, android, timer, onresume

Im using a `Timer` to continuously update a `TextView`, but I'm having trouble restarting the timer during the `onResume()` method. I use `timer.cancel()` in the `onPause()` and `onDestroy()` methods, but how do I restart the timer in `onResume()`?

This is my timer code...

```
int delay = 1000; 
int period = 1000; 
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

public void run() {
        //I update the TextView here 
    }

}, delay, period);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont restart the timer. Instead use a new timer i.e inside onResume() create a new timer. As you are no longer using the previous one, garbage collection will take care of it. So in onResume() use the following code:

```
timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

public void run() {

    //update the TextView here 

}

}, delay, period);
```

Comment: But I thought that you can't update GUI using timer because it creates a new thread and does nto execute on the main UI thread

Comment: @Snake: Some GUI update functions work when called from non-GUI threads but that is not well documented. For other functions which cant be called outside of GUI thread, we can use runOnGUIThread() function if absolutely necessary. I would rather use Handler to do this kind of task.

Answer (score 5):

An easier alternative is to use the `Handler` class. I wouldn't recommend the Timer class because it has no bearing on the life cycle of your Activity and you will have to worry about any potential threading problems yourself. The beauty of using the Handler is that all your callbacks will be on the main thread (so no threading issues to worry about). The following is a simple example on how to do this.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   ....
   mHandler = new Handler();
}

 @Override
protected void onResume() 
{
     mHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, UPDATE_RATE);
}

 @Override
protected void onPause() 
{
     mHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
}

 private final Runnable myRunnable= new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run()
    { 
       //Do task
       mHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, UPDATE_RATE);
    }
 }
```